# Control code coverage attachments in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

In a multi-stage, yaml configured CI pipeline that builds in Windows and Linux via matrix strategy I'm generating:

- A `.cobertura.xml` file in Linux os, used to produce an aggregated report via [ReportsGenerator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Palmmedia.reportgenerator) that is accesible from coverage tab in AzureDevops. I'm explicitly using `PublishCodeCoverageResults` in this os.
- A `.coverage` file in Windows os, to feed SonarCloud with coverage data. I'm not using `PublishCodeCoverageResults` in this os.

My issue is that `.coverage` file overrides the expected report in coverage tab, allowing me to download it rather than seeing the report. How can I avoid that? Is there any way to get rid of that attachment to properly show the report?

---

If I don't run the Windows part, the report is [shown as expected](https://dev.azure.com/eduherminio/SheepTools/_build/results?buildId=306&view=codecoverage-tab).

If I do it, I get [this](https://dev.azure.com/eduherminio/SheepTools/_build/results?buildId=308&view=codecoverage-tab) rather than the report.

I've tried removing `.coverage` files at the end of the pipeline, but the 'attachment' in coverage tab stays there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/1069092/view.html):

> This is not a bug and the behavior is as designed as the .coverage
> report is given precedence over other reports.
>
> My guidance would be to stop publishing the test run as part of the
> dotnet task in windows. There is an option to do so.
>
> Copy the trx and coverage files out to separate locations. Upload the
> trx file using the publish test results task but make sure the
> coverage file is not available for this publish.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood you want to have download avialble instead of displaying code coverage like this:

[image: Code covereage view]

But your code coverage is also available as an artifact:

[image: An artidact to download for Azure DevOps]

So you can still download it:

[image: Artifact details]

Does it help you somehow?

Comment: Hmm not exactly, I just need to have the code coverage displayed.
However, I only get this: https://dev.azure.com/eduherminio/SheepTools/_build/results?buildId=308&view=codecoverage-tab

When I don't generate `.coverage` files, I can see it:
https://dev.azure.com/eduherminio/SheepTools/_build/results?buildId=306&view=codecoverage-tab

Comment: Sure, but bear in mind that it just works when no `.coverage` files are generated in the other os.
https://github.com/eduherminio/SheepTools/blob/d4616e3ac93502a3b482eb628f7aeee49cfe7124/azure-pipelines.yml#L59